# How to pull a nested ID from a Json payload

Tags: json, token

I am trying to get to an ID in a Json payload I'm receiving but now matter how I write my token, I can't seem to get to it.

[JsonPayload screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHvQ2.png)

I've written it a number of different ways, but none work. Only {id} and {portfolioItem} get replaced, but neither are what I need. The former giving "not-2fd82a8f" which I don't need, and the latter, giving me the entire object.

```
test1={id}&
test2={portfolioItem}&
test3={portfolioItem.id}&
test6={portfolioItem[0].id}&
test9={portfolioItem[id]}&
test4={{portfolioItem.id}}&
test5={{$..portfolioItem.id}}&
test7={{$..portfolioItem[0].id}}&
test8={{$..portfolioItem[id]}}&
```

Can someone clue me into what I might be missing? Thank you very much.

Comment: What language are you writing this *in*?